# Cannot POST to Trello API even when authenticated

Tags: rest, oauth, trello

I've been trying to get a Google Apps Script up and running to move spreadsheet entries into a Trello board each time a form is completed. I'm testing the OAuth1 flow, but regardless of how I authenticate, I cannot `POST` anything (`GET` requests have worked so far on everything except `cards`). I've confirmed the apps have the necessary read/write permissions in my account settings.

For testing purposes, I used the Single Use Token option in Trello via the following URL:

`https://trello.com/1/authorize?name=SingleUseTesting&expiration=never&scope=read,write&key=MYKEY`

Authorizing showed that the app had permission to read and write to my account.

Authorization showed up in my account dashboard as read/write enabled.

I can get a response for my cards from:

`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/LIST_ID/cards`

When I try to `POST` via the API URL using the following:

`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/57a0b90f8b1740162702fa22/cards?&name=testing&due=null&key=MYKEY&token=MYTOKEN`

I get an error saying the token is invalid. I even went so far as to revoke access to all other apps to see if it was checking the wrong token for some reason, but with no change in result.

I need to make sure the `POST` URI works to send the `payload` object from Google Apps Scripts successfully, but I can't get beyond this step. Any insight on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution isn't in the Trello documents (that I can find), so I'm posting it here in case others run into the same problem.

Since Google has dropped the OAuth1 library objects and methods, it's much easier to request a perpetual token for your Trello API key through a URL. But, in order for that to work, you have to set the `request_type` to `token` in the URL.

The authorization request should look like this:

`https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=YOUR_APP_KEY&name=APP_NAME&scope=read,write&expiration=never&response_type=token`

The returned page has a string which is included in the `payload` to authenticate the write request for the API key.

A full, working code example can be found in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/bennettscience/1cff02b031fd65cf3fd2ce433760b64a).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here's what I found.

If you have your application working with GET requests, you should have a fetch URL that looks something like this:

```
var url="https://api.trello.com/1/boards/MY_BOARD_ID/lists";
```

Unless you specify otherwise, GET requests are the default method in Trello API.
For the other three types (PUT, POST and DELETE) you need to pass the request method as parameter.

Here's how it's coded on my script:

```
var url="https://api.trello.com/1/cards/MY_CARD_ID/pos?value=top";
var options={"method":"put"};
var response=service.fetch(url,options);
```

As you can see on this snippet of code, the actual request parameters are passed through the URL and the method inside the options variable. My guess is that you can also send it via payload object inside the options variable, but I'm too lazy to test it right now.
The methods to be used with each request are described on Trello API documentation:
https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference

I hope it helps.